# @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'AccountStatus')

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js

Few minutes ago, my application was running ok. Suddenly, variables start to get undefined and I get error messages. I had tried to build this app using laravel but kept having issues. Now I am working with Vue.js. These are my codes below:

service.js

```
import firebase from "../firebase";
// var whereis = "Deliverers.Profile";
const db = firebase.ref("/Deliverers");

class Service {
  getAll() {
    return db;
  }

//   create(tutorial) {
//     return db.push(tutorial);
//   }

  update(key, value) {
    return db.child(key).update(value);
  }

//   delete(key) {
//     return db.child(key).remove();
//   }

//   deleteAll() {
//     return db.remove();
//   }
}

export default new Service();
```

user.vue

```
<template>
  <div v-if="currentTutorial" class="edit-form">
    <h4>Tutorial</h4>
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          id="title"
          v-model="currentTutorial.user['FullName']"
        />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="description">Description</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          id="description"
          v-model="currentTutorial.user['description']"
        />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label><strong>Status:</strong></label>
        <!-- {{ currentTutorial.status ? "Published" : "Pending" }} -->
        {{ currentTutorial.status }}
      </div>
    </form>

    <button
      class="badge badge-primary mr-2"
      v-if="currentTutorial.published"
      @click="updatePublished(false)"
    >
      UnPublish
    </button>
    <button
      v-else
      class="badge badge-primary mr-2"
      @click="updatePublished(true)"
    >
      Publish
    </button>

    <button class="badge badge-danger mr-2" @click="deleteTutorial">
      Delete
    </button>

    <button type="submit" class="badge badge-success" @click="updateTutorial">
      Update
    </button>
    <p>{{ message }}</p>
  </div>

  <div v-else>
    <br />
    <p>Please click on a Tutorial...</p>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Service from "../services/service";

export default {
  name: "tutorial",
  props: ["tutorial"],
  data() {
    return {
      currentTutorial: null,
      message: "",
    };
  },
  watch: {
    tutorial: function(tutorial) {
      this.currentTutorial = { ...tutorial };
      this.message = "";
    },
  },
  methods: {
    updatePublished(status) {
      Service.update(this.currentTutorial.key, {
        published: status,
      })
        .then(() => {
          this.currentTutorial.published = status;
          this.message = "The status was updated successfully!";
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    },

    updateTutorial() {
      const data = {
        title: this.currentTutorial.title,
        // description: this.currentTutorial.description,
      };

      Service.update(this.currentTutorial.key, data)
        .then(() => {
          this.message = "The tutorial was updated successfully!";
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    },

    deleteTutorial() {
      Service.delete(this.currentTutorial.key)
        .then(() => {
          this.$emit("refreshList");
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.message = "";
    this.currentTutorial = { ...this.tutorial }
  },
};
</script>
```

userlist.vue
EDITED: To replace the faulty function with a working version.

```
<template>
  <div class="list row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <h4>Tutorials List</h4>
      <ul class="list-group">
        <li
          class="list-group-item"
          :class="{ active: index == currentIndex }"
          v-for="(tutorial, index) in tutorials"
          :key="index"
          @click="setActiveTutorial(tutorial, index)"
        >
          {{ tutorial.user.Email}}
        </li>
      </ul>

      <button class="m-3 btn btn-sm btn-danger" @click="removeAllTutorials">
        Remove All
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <div v-if="currentTutorial">
        <tutorial-details
          :tutorial="currentTutorial"
          @refreshList="refreshList"
        />
      </div>
      <div v-else>
        <br />
        <p>Please click on a Tutorial...</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Service from "../services/service";
import TutorialDetails from "./user";
 
export default {
  name: "tutorials-list",
  components: { TutorialDetails },
  data() {
    return {
      tutorials: [],
      currentTutorial: null,
      currentIndex: -1
    };
  },
  methods: {
    // onDataChange() {
    //  snapshot => {
    //   let data = snapshot.val();
    //   let _tutorials = [];
    //   Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
    //     _tutorials.push({
    //      key: key,
    //       username: data[key].profile.fullname,
    //       // text: data[key].text}
    //      });
    //   });
    //   this.tutorials = _tutorials;
    // };

    // },


//THIS METHOD WORKED!!
      onDataChange(snapshot) {
      let data = snapshot.val();
      let _tutorials = [];
      Object.keys(data).forEach(key => {
         _tutorials.push({
         key: key,
         user: data[key].Profile,
         });
      });
      this.tutorials = _tutorials;
     },

    refreshList() {
      this.currentTutorial = null;
      this.currentIndex = -1;
    },

    setActiveTutorial(tutorial, index) {
      this.currentTutorial = tutorial;
      this.currentIndex = index;
    },

    removeAllTutorials() {
      Service.deleteAll()
        .then(() => {
          this.refreshList();
        })
        .catch((e) => {
          console.log(e);
        });
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    Service.getAll().on("value", this.onDataChange);
    // Service.getAll().on("value", function(snapshot){
    //   var data = snapshot.val();
    //   for(let i in data){
    //     console.log(data[i].Profile.Email);
    //   }
    // });
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    Service.getAll().off("value", this.onDataChange);
  }
};
</script>
```

Console.log(data) gives this result - which is what I expect it to do:

```
{AccountStatus: 'Verified', Address: 'Abakaliki', BirthYear: '1999', DeliveryOn: false, Email: 'www@gmail.com', …}
userslist.vue?8b1e:73 
{AccountStatus: 'Unverified', Address: 'Amaeke Ekoli Edda Afikpo South LGA Ebonyi state', BirthYear: '1985', Date: 1640599050717, DeliveryOn: false, …}
userslist.vue?8b1e:73 
{AccountStatus: 'Verified', Address: '7 glibert street kpirikpiri abakalik', BirthYear: '1973', Date: 1638213915413, DeliveryOn: false, …}
```

console.log(data.AccountStatus) gives the right results as shown below:

```
Verified
Unverified
Verified
```

console.log("items is:\n", JSON.stringify(items, null, 2)); gives the following output

```
items is:
 {
  "1UWuDwL2WvWndqgUBweoUjeEEZk1": {
    "Bank details": {
      "accountName": "Samuel Ankkk",
      "accountNumber": "234567890",
      "bank": "wensBANK"
    },
    "Location": {
      "latitude": "9.0691414",
      "longitude": "7.4a424",
      "state": "Abuja"
    },
    "Profile": {
      "AccountStatus": "Verified",
      "Address": "Area B Opp Living Faith Church ",
      "BirthYear": "1984",
      "DeliveryOn": false,
      "Email": "hyu@gmail.com",
      "From": "Federal Capital Territory",
      "Fullname": "Samuel jui",
      "IdImage": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/lombaz-3490e.appspot.com/o/ID_Pictures%2FNational%20ID%2F1612350737409.jpg?alt=media&token=640b2544-a9af-4f86-b7d8-3d47f638f77f",
      "Image": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/lombaz-3490e.appspot.com/o/Profile%20Pictures%2F1612350733949.jpg?alt=media&token=617d6b6b-50bd-4898-abdc-be53e70612bd",
      "Phone_number": "08062093434",
      "Route": "Jibowu",
      "State": "Kogi State",
      "To": "Lagos State",
      "carrier": "Traveller || Individual",
      "routed": "Federal Capital Territory - Jibowu"
    }
  },
  "1WAVu8OUYzN7EudSc4vs55GUGYg1": {
    "Profile": {
      "AccountStatus": "Verified",
      "Address": "ohuru amangwu obingwa ogbohill Aba Abia state nigeria",
      "BirthYear": "1994",
      "Date": 1631033704355,
      "DeliveryOn": false,
      "Email": "kui@gmail.com",
      "Fullname": "Sunday vh",
      "IdImage": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/lombaz-3490e.appspot.com/o/ID_Pictures%2FOthers%2F1631033692952.jpg?alt=media&token=71967d4d-4a7f-4669-a7e1-9e2968970c2f",
      "Image": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/lombaz-3490e.appspot.com/o/Profile%20Pictures%2F1631033678872.jpg?alt=media&token=71f2f23c-ffa7-4bb7-a82a-d16949e0971f",
      "Phone_number": "09064491585",
      "Route": "None",
      "State": "Abia State",
      "routed": "None"
    }
  },
  "1sLWwcxZL8Sr1sBFAzuPDcl1iXs1": {
    "Bank details": {
      "accountName": "Ekoh Jety",
      "accountNumber": "67808870",
      "bank": "first Bank"
    },
    "Location": {
      "latitude": "5.3872821",
      "longitude": "7.0089u9u8"
    },
    "Profile": {
      "AccountStatus": "Verified",
      "Address": "No 2 Obuagu, Enugu",
      "BirthYear": "1998",
      "DeliveryOn": false,
      "Email": "j.fffg@gmail.com",
      "From": "Enugu State",
      "Fullname": "Ekoh wwiiwC.",
      "IdImage": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/lombaz-3490e.appspot.com/o/ID_Pictures%2FNational%20ID%2F1609831737206.jpg?alt=media&token=8290066b-73ab-44d0-8807-c28af6592b0e",
      "Image": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/lombaz-3490e.appspot.com/o/Profile%20Pictures%2F1609831730721.jpg?alt=media&token=6efe967a-58eb-4fa7-b841-81d3d7666eb1",
      "Phone_number": "08100489261",
      "Route": "Emene Axis (Enugu Int’l Airport)",
      "State": "Enugu State",
      "To": "Enugu State",
      "carrier": "Traveller || Individual",
      "routed": "Enugu State - Emene Axis (Enugu Int’l Airport)"
    }
  }
}
```

On the console, Console.log(data) displays fine. Then this warning and error follows:

```
index.esm.js?abfd:106 [2022-02-05T15:39:46.784Z]  @firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: Exception was thrown by user callback. TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'AccountStatus')
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/userslist.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&:84:24)
    at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.esm.js:4345:20)
    at LLRBNode.inorderTraversal (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.esm.js:2697:15)
    at LLRBNode.inorderTraversal (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.esm.js:2696:27)
    at LLRBNode.inorderTraversal (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.esm.js:2698:24)
    at LLRBNode.inorderTraversal (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.esm.js:2696:27)
    at SortedMap.inorderTraversal (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.esm.js:3147:27)
    at ChildrenNode.forEachChild (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.esm.js:3756:35)
    at DataSnapshot.forEach (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.esm.js:4344:31)
    at VueComponent.onDataChange (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js?!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/index.js?!./src/components/userslist.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&:76:13) 
defaultLogHandler @ index.esm.js?abfd:106
Logger.warn @ index.esm.js?abfd:212
warn @ index.esm.js?e947:348
eval @ index.esm.js?e947:704
setTimeout (async)
exceptionGuard @ index.esm.js?e947:698
EventList.raise @ index.esm.js?e947:9565
EventQueue.raiseQueuedEventsMatchingPredicate_ @ index.esm.js?e947:9519
EventQueue.raiseEventsForChangedPath @ index.esm.js?e947:9503
Repo.onDataUpdate_ @ index.esm.js?e947:12730
PersistentConnection.onDataPush_ @ index.esm.js?e947:12006
PersistentConnection.onDataMessage_ @ index.esm.js?e947:12000
Connection.onDataMessage_ @ index.esm.js?e947:11246
Connection.onPrimaryMessageReceived_ @ index.esm.js?e947:11240
eval @ index.esm.js?e947:11141
WebSocketConnection.appendFrame_ @ index.esm.js?e947:10727
WebSocketConnection.handleIncomingFrame @ index.esm.js?e947:10772
mySock.onmessage @ index.esm.js?e947:10673
index.esm.js?e947:705 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'AccountStatus')
    at eval (userslist.vue?8b1e:77:1)
    at eval (index.esm.js?e947:4331:1)
    at LLRBNode.inorderTraversal (index.esm.js?e947:2683:1)
    at LLRBNode.inorderTraversal (index.esm.js?e947:2682:1)
    at LLRBNode.inorderTraversal (index.esm.js?e947:2684:1)
    at LLRBNode.inorderTraversal (index.esm.js?e947:2682:1)
    at SortedMap.inorderTraversal (index.esm.js?e947:3133:1)
    at ChildrenNode.forEachChild (index.esm.js?e947:3742:1)
    at DataSnapshot.forEach (index.esm.js?e947:4330:1)
    at VueComponent.onDataChange (userslist.vue?8b1e:70:1)
eval @ userslist.vue?8b1e:77
eval @ index.esm.js?e947:4331
LLRBNode.inorderTraversal @ index.esm.js?e947:2683
LLRBNode.inorderTraversal @ index.esm.js?e947:2682
LLRBNode.inorderTraversal @ index.esm.js?e947:2684
LLRBNode.inorderTraversal @ index.esm.js?e947:2682
SortedMap.inorderTraversal @ index.esm.js?e947:3133
ChildrenNode.forEachChild @ index.esm.js?e947:3742
DataSnapshot.forEach @ index.esm.js?e947:4330
onDataChange @ userslist.vue?8b1e:70
onceCallback @ index.esm.js?e947:4935
eval @ index.esm.js?e947:4545
exceptionGuard @ index.esm.js?e947:694
EventList.raise @ index.esm.js?e947:9565
EventQueue.raiseQueuedEventsMatchingPredicate_ @ index.esm.js?e947:9519
EventQueue.raiseEventsForChangedPath @ index.esm.js?e947:9503
Repo.onDataUpdate_ @ index.esm.js?e947:12730
PersistentConnection.onDataPush_ @ index.esm.js?e947:12006
PersistentConnection.onDataMessage_ @ index.esm.js?e947:12000
Connection.onDataMessage_ @ index.esm.js?e947:11246
Connection.onPrimaryMessageReceived_ @ index.esm.js?e947:11240
eval @ index.esm.js?e947:11141
WebSocketConnection.appendFrame_ @ index.esm.js?e947:10727
WebSocketConnection.handleIncomingFrame @ index.esm.js?e947:10772
mySock.onmessage @ index.esm.js?e947:10673
setTimeout (async)
exceptionGuard @ index.esm.js?e947:698
EventList.raise @ index.esm.js?e947:9565
EventQueue.raiseQueuedEventsMatchingPredicate_ @ index.esm.js?e947:9519
EventQueue.raiseEventsForChangedPath @ index.esm.js?e947:9503
Repo.onDataUpdate_ @ index.esm.js?e947:12730
PersistentConnection.onDataPush_ @ index.esm.js?e947:12006
PersistentConnection.onDataMessage_ @ index.esm.js?e947:12000
Connection.onDataMessage_ @ index.esm.js?e947:11246
Connection.onPrimaryMessageReceived_ @ index.esm.js?e947:11240
eval @ index.esm.js?e947:11141
WebSocketConnection.appendFrame_ @ index.esm.js?e947:10727
WebSocketConnection.handleIncomingFrame @ index.esm.js?e947:10772
mySock.onmessage @ index.esm.js?e947:10673
```

Before this error, I could see a list of all the emails and clicking on each, displays other details.
Suddenly, everything went south. I have cleared cache, still nothing changed. In fact, nothing displays in Microsoft edge, no warning, nothing in console at all.The errors are seen on chrome.

Any help will be appreciated please. Thanks

Comment: "`console.log(data)` displays fine" What does it display? And what about `console.log(data.AccountStatus)`?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec, Thanks for reaching out. I have updated my question to include the data logged to console. Please take a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Watch out for asynchronous processes

`console.log(data)` can have a confusing output, because what you see in the console is what the value of `data` is *at the time you are looking*, which may not have been the value at the time it was actually printed to the console.

To avoid this, I suggest changing the console.log to the following:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(data,null,2));
```

Doing a JSON.stringify forces Javascript to evaluate the object on-the-spot and turn it into a string.

I bet you a virtual $10 bill that when you make that change, you will see that `data` is rubbish at that time.

#### Why I am confident that `data` is at fault

Your error message was:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'AccountStatus')
```

This means that you were asking Javascript to read `undefined.AccountStatus`. The only place you could be doing that, i.e. the only place the word "AccountStatus" exists in your code, is here:

```
    let key = item.key;
    let data = item.val().Profile;
    console.log(data);
    _tutorials.push({
       key: key,
       status: data.AccountStatus,   //  ☚
       email: data.Email,
    });
```

This means that `data` must be undefined.

So if what you were printing out looked good, that must be a later value of `data`.

#### Surely the parameter to `onDataChange` should be a snapshot, not an array?

```js
onDataChange(snapshot) {
  const items = snapshot.val()

  console.log("items is:\n", JSON.stringify(items, null, 2));
        
  let _tutorials = [];
  items.forEach((item) => {
    let key = item.key;
    let data = item.Profile;
    _tutorials.push({
      key: key,
      status: data.AccountStatus,
      email: data.Email,
    });
  });

  this.tutorials = _tutorials;
}
```

#### Solution: `items` is now an object, rather than an array!

You say the code was working before, i.e. you were able to run

```
items.forEach( )
```

That means `items` was (before you made the change to the database) an array. That way, the elements of `items` were the `item` value, which in turn have the correct properties, including `.AccountStatus`.

In the current state of your database, it is clear that `items` is *not* an array at all! It is an object.

An array would appear like this:

```
items is:
 [
    {
    "Bank details": {
      "accountName": "Samuel Ankkk",
      "accountNumber": "234567890",
      "bank": "wensBANK"
    },
    "Location": {
      "latitude": "9.0691414",
      "longitude": "7.4a424",
      "state": "Abuja"
    },
    "Profile": {
      "AccountStatus": "Verified",
      "Address": "Area B Opp Living Faith Church ",
   ...
```

But what you are seeing is this:

```
items is:
 {
  "1UWuDwL2WvWndqgUBweoUjeEEZk1": {
    "Bank details": {
      "accountName": "Samuel Ankkk",
      "accountNumber": "234567890",
      "bank": "wensBANK"
    },
    "Location": {
      "latitude": "9.0691414",
      "longitude": "7.4a424",
      "state": "Abuja"
    },
    "Profile": {
      "AccountStatus": "Verified",
      "Address": "Area B Opp Living Faith Church ",
    ...
```

In other words, an array looks like this:

```
[ { "key": value, "anotherKey": anotherValue}, 
  { "key": value2,  ...                     }, 
  ...
]
```

This can be accessed with `.forEach`

In contrast, an object looks like this:

{
"itemKey1": { "key": value, "anotherKey": anotherValue},
"itemKey2": { "key": value2, ...                      }
}

It cannot be accessed by `.forEach`. That is the error you are seeing.

#### What I think happened

You unknowingly changed the structure of `items` in Firebase. Instead of writing an array (or equivalently an object with keys 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 etc) you are now writing a real object with string keys.

#### Solution

Convert the object to an array, for example like this. Change this line:

```
items.forEach((item) => {
```

to this:

```
Object.values(items).forEach((item) => {
```

This is assuming you don't need the key of the item, e.g. "1UWuDwL2WvWndqgUBweoUjeEEZk1". To me, this string looks like a Firebase User ID. If so, you probably do want to extract it. For example:

```
Object.keys(items).forEach(userId => {
   const item = items[userId];
```

Comment: Thanks! I have taken your suggestions and:
 With JSON.stringify, i still get all the data correct. 
However, with the snapshot, i get this error: "TypeError: items.forEach is not a function". 
Is there something else I am not doing well?

Comment: 1. Are you still seeing the same error as before, in the same line as before? 
2. I have updated the console log statement: try it out and add to the question what it prints. From what you have said so far, it seems that "items" is not an array, for some reason.

Comment: 1. Yes please, it gave the same error as before. 2 .I have tried out the new code, and updated my question to include the output. However, the error persists.

Comment: Excellent - the revised console.log gives us exactly the information needed to diagnose what has happened. I have updated the answer. Remember to mark as Accepted if it solves the problem you described. 8-)

Comment: Thanks so much for pointing me in the right direction and saving my sanity. I am grateful. 
I have updated my userlist.ve & user.vue to include the correct functions and how I was able to access data. And Yes, your answer is accepted.